# Recess and Drupal Friend or Not?

Tags: drupal, recess

I want to develop back-end of iphone app using recess for services layer component. This app will also have web app using same services layer component. I want to develop wep app using some CMS(Drupal) . I m confuse about databases . Since services layer will have its own database and drupal will have its own. But it is never a good idea to use two databases for same application.
Kindly suggest alternatives.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Recess allows you to specify which database server to connect to. To accomplish your goal of a shared database, configure Recess to use the same database as Drupal. I recommend at least using a different user account to store your Recess data. That will still allow you to merge/migrate data down the road, should you need it. (Although to me, that sounds highly unlikely.)

Alternatively, consider Recess and Drupal to be different applications, which they are.